# Eclipse is saying that static field of a class cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse

Despite the [HttpComponents documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.3.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy.html) saying that the class `DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy` has a static field called `INSTANCE`, Eclipse is telling me that's unresolved.

I've tried everything I know of (checked the version, rebuilt the code etc) but nothing makes it go away. 
Does anyone know what could be causing this problem?

[image: Eclipse problem]

Code is:

```
socket = serverSocket.accept();
                DefaultBHttpServerConnectionFactory connFactory = DefaultBHttpServerConnectionFactory.INSTANCE;
                HttpServerConnection conn = connFactory.createConnection(socket);
                ConnectionReuseStrategy connReuseStrat = DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy.INSTANCE;
                HttpService httpService = new HttpService(httpproc, connReuseStrat, new DefaultHttpResponseFactory(), null, null);
                HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext(null);
                httpService.handleRequest(conn, context);
```

Answer (score 2):

The version of Apache HTTPComponents included in Eclipse is 4.2.x which does not have the INSTANCE field - this appears to be new in 4.3